# How do I intall a older Python version than my current 3.8.5?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and want to install a detection tool for a Lidar sensor. This tool requires Tensorflow version 1.13.0 or a simmilar one. I figured out that the newest version doesn't have a command which is used in this tool. I also figured out that the version 1.13.0 is only available at an older python version like 3.6 or 3.7. I also don't know if Tensorflow 1.13.0 is available because I read that only 1.15.0 or newer versions are supported until now.I already tried installing an older python version with "sudo apt-get python3.7" and it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can install the older Python and Tensorflow?

Comment: If you mess with the version of Python you will no longer have a working Ubuntu machine. It uses Python for many internal things such as the terminal for one.

Comment: Is there any other way to download a functional version of tensorflow with the tfconfig module?

Comment: Sorry I do not know. Hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try using a virtual env for your development efforts.

Try the below thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/8029019

Comment: I had to install Ubuntu 18.04 because of a software which needed this version and now I have Python 3.6.x I think. Anyway, thank you for your answer.